# sql: select * and with min value without filter row

Tags: mysql, sql

Table: Users

```
id, age  
0   1
1   2
3   3
4   60
5   64
```

SQL:

```
SELECT *, MAX(value) FROM Users
```

---

Result (I want below result)

```
id, age, max age, isMax
0   1       64          false
1   2       64          false
3   3       64          false
4   60      64          false
5   64      64          true
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.11-MariaDB

Comment: It is unclear to me how adding these columns makes the *delete* faster.  Your question is rather confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `MAX` as a [window function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions-overview/), specifying the window as the whole table (no `PARTITION BY` clause):

```
select *,
    MAX(value) OVER () as `max value`,
    CASE WHEN MAX(value) OVER () = value THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as `is max`
from @t
```

Comment: Working, `over()` is solve any problem, Thanks